# Actions-on-Google NodeJS library

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

*agent* is a *WebhookClient* **Object** from dialogflow-fulfillment library

```
let conv = agent.conv();
conv.ask('Sample Title');
conv.ask('Sample Next Line');
conv.close(new Suggestions('Lets Go!!', 'Awesome!!'));
agent.add(conv)
```

I am getting weird error despite following the documentation.

- Case 1: 
  If I dont use conv.close() I am getting error - ***MalformedResponse 'final_response' must be set***
- Case 2:
  If I use conv.close() with Simple Rich Media element like Suggestions, I am getting the error ***MalformedResponse
  final_response.rich_response: 'item[2]' must not be empty.***

Case 3: 
If it is simple case like below it is working

> ```
> conv.ask('Title');
> conv.close('Next Line');
> agent.add(conv);
> ```

My requirement is simple, I need response with simpleText as well as Rich Text Elements like Suggestions, Cards, Images. Now I have not been able to acheive it yet using the actions on google library because it keeps on throwing the above mentioned errors

Thanks in advance for any help